# React Native Switch doesn't work inside a drawer navigator, but works inside a stack navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have 2 pages, test.js in Stack.Navigator and drawertest.js in Drawer.Navigator with the exact same code for a switch using Switch from react native. However, the drawertest.js switch doesn't react to any click, but the test.js switch works perfect. Why is this? I want to use the switch in a page in my drawer but it just does not want to work.

test.js and drawertest.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Image, Switch } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation, useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';

function Drawertest() {
    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
    const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

    return (
        <Switch 
            trackColor={{false: COLORS.darkThemeColor, true: COLORS.darkBeige}}
            thumbColor={isEnabled ? COLORS.themeColor : COLORS.themeColor}
            onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
            value={isEnabled}
        />
  );
}

export default Drawertest;
```

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Text, Button, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerToggleButton } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { SplashScreen } from 'expo-router';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

import Test from './test';
import About from './about';
import Settings from './settings';
import Statistics from './statistics';
import Profile from './profile';
import Break from './break';
import Watch from './watch';
import Home from './home';
import styles from '../myComponents/common/header/header/header.style';
import { COLORS, icons, images, FONT, SIZES } from '../constants';
import { ScreenHeaderBtn, TimeSlider, SessionBtn } from '../myComponents';
import Drawertest from './drawertest';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function HomeStack({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName='Home'
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige },
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <ScreenHeaderBtn 
                        iconUrl={icons.menu} 
                        dimension="60%" 
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                    />
                ),
                headerTitle: () => (
                    <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Flowtime</Text>
                ),
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Watch" component={Watch} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Break" component={Break} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

function App() {
    // State variable appIsReady tracks when app is ready to render
    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

    // Load fonts
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        MontBold: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
        MontMed: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
        MontReg: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      });
    
    // useEffect hook calls prepare function
    useEffect(() => {
        async function prepare() {
            try {
                // Keeps SplashScreen visible until the app is ready
                await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
            } catch (error) {
                // If line above results in an error, error logs to console
                console.warn(error);
            } finally {
                setAppIsReady(true);

                if (fontsLoaded) {
                    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        prepare();
    }, [fontsLoaded]);

    // useCallback creates a memoized callback onLayoutRootView that only changes appIsReady / fontsLoaded changes
    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (appIsReady && fontsLoaded) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [appIsReady, fontsLoaded]);
        
        if (!appIsReady || !fontsLoaded) {
            return null;
        }

    return (
        <NavigationContainer onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
            <Drawer.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Main"
                backBehavior='initialRoute'
                screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                    headerStyle: { 
                        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige,
                        shadowColor: "#000",
                        shadowOffset: {
                            width: 0,
                            height: 2,
                        },
                        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                        shadowRadius: 3.84,
                        elevation: 5,
                    },
                    headerLeft: () => {
                        const navigation = useNavigation();
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.backButton}>
                                <ScreenHeaderBtn
                                    iconUrl={icons.left}
                                    dimension='60%'
                                    title='goBack'
                                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')}
                                />
                            </View>
                        )
                    },
                    headerTitle: route.name,
                    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                    headerTitleStyle: styles.headerStyle,
                    headerShadowVisible: true,
                    drawerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightBeige,
                        width: 200,
                    },
                    drawerLabelStyle: {
                        color: COLORS.themeColor,
                        fontFamily: FONT.medium,
                    },
                    drawerActiveTintColor: 'gray',
                })}
            >
                <Drawer.Screen name="Main" children={(props) => <HomeStack {...props}/>} options={{ drawerItemStyle: { height: 0 }, headerShown: false}}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" children={Profile} options={{headerTitle: 'Profile'}}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Statistics" children={Statistics} options={{headerTitle: 'Statistics'}}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" children={Settings} options={{headerTitle: 'Settings'}}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="About" children={About} options={{headerTitle: 'About'}}/>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Drawertest" children={Drawertest} options={{headerTitle: 'DrawerTest'}}/>
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default App;
```